# SQL 2008. How to let user to create/alter sprocs in only one particular schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration, permissions

I have a user which can read and write but now he needs to be able to create/alter a sproc but giving him ddl_admin will make it too unsecure. I dont trust him that much.

What can I do about it? Can I somehow give him rights to alter a sproc in only one schema (I will create a schema for his own use)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2005+ have far more granular permissions

```
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO MyRoleorUser
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA:TheSchemaName TO MyRoleorUser
```

"ddl_admin" is simply a legacy wrapper for these new permissions

From [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) in MSDN

> Requires CREATE PROCEDURE permission in the database and ALTER permission on the schema in which the procedure is being created.

Edit:

If your schema is only for stored procs then you should be OK, with no side effects such as the ability to change permissions or createtables